# How to put a listener on the animation of a dialog disappearing?

Tags: android, android-dialog

When a dialog is disappearing, it can look bad if you have another animation running at the same that takes up a large portion of the screen. I've also found that a disappearing dialog doesn't mix well with `listView.smoothScrollToPosition()`.

Is it possible to put a listener on the dialog disappearing animation so that you can start your own animation or scrolling when it has completely gone?

I will accept the answer of "no it isn't possible" if someone can convince me of that.

Comment: Not related to the animation part, but is [`Dialog.setOnDismissListener()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#setOnDismissListener%28android.content.DialogInterface.OnDismissListener%29) what you want?

Comment: I'll give it a try, but I'm guessing that event is triggered at the beginning of the dialog's exit rather than the end.